# parse function not working

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle, jsp

I have the following code:

```
String date_p = request.getParameter("myText");
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    java.util.Date frmDate = sdf.parse(date_p);
```

I get the error as:

```
type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /demo3.jsp at line 22

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /demo3.jsp at line 22

19: 
20:     String date_p = request.getParameter("myText");
21:     DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
22:     java.util.Date frmDate = sdf.parse(date_p);

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:575)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)



root cause 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jsp.demo3_jsp._jspService(demo3_jsp.java:106)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Why is the parse function not working?
I have imported these packages as well - "java.sql.*, java.util.*, java.text.*"

Comment: yes your problem is an NPE, read your stacktrace

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Its a JSP page. date_p value is taken from the user. I cannot understand the problem here

Answer (score 2):

your `date_p` seems to be null , you need to check that you have passed an attribute `myText` in your GET param or POST param.

Comment: It is present in the code:  
<FORM action="demo3.jsp" method="post"> 
 <H1>Interface Table</H1>
<tr>
  <td>Text:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="myText" id="myText" value=""></td>
  <td><input type="submit" value="Click to Submit"></td>
</tr>
 <%

 String date_p = request.getParameter("myText");
 DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
 java.util.Date frmDate = sdf.parse(date_p);

Comment: <td><input type="text" name="myText" id="myText" value="">  value is null as Mifmif said

Comment: what do you want to do with your `frmDate` ? in the first load of your page there is no parameter passed in the request, so you will get null for `date_p`

Comment: pass data to servlet when submit button is clicked
String date_p = request.getParameter("myText"); 
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
java.util.Date frmDate = sdf.parse(date_p);
It will work